# Jackson's @JsonView annotation does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I annotated class User with @JsonView and when it returned I see all fields even than that not contains in view class. Here is my class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userID;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="user_name")
private String firstName;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="user_last_name")
private String lastName;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="phone")
private String phone;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="origin")
private String address;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="birth_date")
private Long birthDate;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="gender")
private Long gender;
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@Column(name="about_me")
private String aboutMe;
@JsonView(View.SummaryWithPhoto.class)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="photo")
private Photo avatar;
@JsonView(View.SummaryWithSession.class)
@Transient
private UserSession session;

//getters and setters
```

Here is my View class

```
public class View {
public interface Summary {}
public interface SummaryWithPhoto extends Summary {}
public interface SummaryWithSession extends SummaryWithPhoto {}
}
```

SO then I request get method with `@JsonView(View.SummaryWithPhoto.class)` annotation I always get userID field but shouldn't. Here is endpoint code

```
@JsonView(View.SummaryWithPhoto.class)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestHeader(value="Access-key") String accessKey,
                                     @RequestHeader(value="Secret-key") String secretKey)
```

Comment: Show your endpoint code.

Comment: Which Jackson version are you on?

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov 2.5.0

Answer (score 5):

I've spend a some debugging time with the same issue.
Results are:

- all fields are included by default if you do not change this behavior (see `BeanSerializerFactory.processViews`). To change default do:

  ```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
  ```
- fields, marked by `@JsonView` omitted in result if controller method annotated with OTHER `@JsonView` (see `FilteredBeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField`)

So for your use-case do not change default settings, annotate `Long userID` by `@JsonView` and `getUser` by any other (not the same) View.

Code `com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.4\jackson-databind-2.8.4-sources.jar!\com\fasterxml\jackson\databind\MapperFeature.java`

```
   * Feature is enabled by default.
   */
   DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION(true)
```

is contradicted of blog https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring, so I have to look at code closer.

Comment: Weird, because way back in 2014, the Spring blog post said the opposite: ```In Spring MVC default configuration, MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION is set to false. ``` https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: Yes, exactly! I have added snip of jackson `MapperFeature` code into my post.

Comment: If you create an ObjectMapper yourself, the MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION is defaulted to true. But spring creates its own ObjectMapper in MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter with the feature set to false.