# JsonView does not work

Tags: json, spring

I use the annotation @JsonView, but it doesn't work, here is my code and the return data, would you please help me to look where I am wrong.

My spring jar shows the edition of "spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar", and I just add this bean,I do not know whether it is useful or not, and I just use @JsonView directly in my code

```
<bean id = "jacksonMessageConverter" class = "org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        </bean>
```

Here is the View class

```
public class View {
    public interface Summary{};
}
```

This is the User entity class(with "set" "get" method omitted), it has several attribute which corresponding to the database, there is a "status" attribute needn't return in the json data.

```
public Class User{
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Integer uid;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String first;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String last;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String email;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String password;

    private Integer status;

}
```

I had the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@ResponseBody
public Message login(String email, String password){        
    User user = userMapper.findUser(email,password);        

    Message message = new Message();                
    message.setUser(user);
    return message;     
}   
}
```

and here is my Message class with the "set" "get" methods

```
public class Message {
    private int box_hits;

    private List<Box> boxes;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private User user;
}
```

when I use the postman to test the url,it shows json data, obviously, it should not return with the attribute without @JsonView, what' wrong with my code?

```
 {
  "box_hits": 0,
  "boxes": null,
  "user": {
    "uid": 1,
    "first": "yuan",
    "last": "kang",
    "email": "123@qq.com",
    "password": "123",
    "status": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: For Spring 4.2 work with `@JsonView` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299334/jacksons-jsonview-annotation-does-not-work#38777244

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As described in [the announcement blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring), this feature is only available as of Spring Framework 4.2. It won't work with Spring 3.2.8.