# JsonView for filtering Json properties in Spring MVC not working

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

In our Spring MVC web application for job recruiting, I work on a RESTful service to get information about available companies for a given account, or more detailed data for a single company.

This is implemented using Spring MVC in a pretty straightforward way.
Logically, the API for a single company shows more details than for a list of companies. In particular, there are two fields (CoverPhoto and Logo) whoch are only to be shown when querying the details for a single company by its id.

For the generation of the Json output, I use Jackson to annotate the returned DTO object for specific field names because sometimes they are different from the member variable names.

One of the ways to implement this in an elegant way is using JsonViews, as described in these tutorials:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

The only difference between them is that the second one uses interfaces for the View classes, and the first one uses classes. But that should not make any difference and my code is not working as expected with either of them.

I have created to interfaces (ObjectList and OblectDetails) and annotated the fields in my DTO with 
    @JsonView(Views.ObjectList.class)
for the fields I want to see on both the lisdt and the details API, and with
    @JsonView(Views.ObjectDetails.class)
for the fields only to shown in the single company API.

But unfortunately, both API's show all fields, regardless of the annotation. Also fields without a @JsonView annotation appear in the output JSON, while according to the documentation, when annotating the Controller method with a @JsonView, each fields should also be annotated with a @JsonView annotation to show up.

My simplified code looks as follows:

DTO:

```
package nl.xxxxxx.dto.too;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "logo", "coverPhoto", "description", "shortDescription",
        "phone", "address"})

public class XxxCompanyDto {

    @JsonView(Views.ObjectList.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.ObjectList.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(Views.ObjectDetails.class)
    private String logo;

    @JsonView(Views.ObjectDetails.class)
    @JsonProperty("cover_photo")
    private String coverPhoto;

    @JsonView(Views.ObjectList.class)
    private String description;

    //more fields

    //setters, no getters are used to prevent ambiguity for Json generation
    //omitted for clarity
}
```

Views:

```
package nl.xxx.dto.too;

public class Views {

    public interface ObjectList {}

    public interface ObjectDetails extends ObjectList {}
}
```

Controller:

```
package nl.xxx.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
//more imports 

/**
 * Created by Klaas van Gelder on 17-Nov-16.
 */

@RestController
public class XxxCompanyController {

    @Autowired
    //services omitted

    @JsonView(Views.ObjectDetails.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/public-api/xxx/company/{companyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public TooCompanyDto getCompanyById(
            @RequestHeader(value = "X-Channel") String publicationChannelToken,
            @PathVariable(value = "companyId") Long companyId) {

        XxxCompany tooCompany = tooCompanyService.getCompanyById(companyId);
        //some verifications omitted
        TooCompanyDto tooCompanyDto = tooCompanyJsonConverter.convertToDto(tooCompany);

        return tooCompanyDto;
    }


    @JsonView(Views.ObjectList.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/public-api/xxx/company", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TooCompanyDto> listCompaniesForChannel(
            @RequestHeader(value = "X-Channel") String publicationChannelToken) {

        XxxPublicationChannel channel = tooVacancyService.findPublicationChannelByToken(publicationChannelToken);
        List<XxxCompany> xxxCompaniesForChannel = xxxCompanyService.findCompaniesByPublicationChannelToken(publicationChannelToken);

        List<XxxCompanyDto> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (XxxCompany xxxCompany : xxxCompaniesForChannel) {
            XxxCompanyDto xxxCompanyDto = xxxCompanyJsonConverter.convertToDto(xxxCompany);
            dtoList.add(xxxCompanyDto);
        }

        return dtoList;
    }
}
```

Maven:
        
        
            org.springframework
            spring-core
            4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    //more depedencies

    with <jackson-2-version>2.2.2</jackson-2-version> in parent POM
```

It seems that the JsonView annotations are completely ignored. I can probably use another solution by using two separate DTO classes but it would be nice to get this working as it should!
Any hints are more than welcome!

Comment: what's your spring framework version?

Comment: please make sure you're using spring 4.2 and also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299334/jacksons-jsonview-annotation-does-not-work#38777244

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was not setting Spring version on all libraries (core, spring-mvc and web). Now I use    <version>4.2.8.RELEASE</version>
for all of them and it works now! The only remaining issue is that the fields not annotated with @JsonView are still shown up in the result while I would expect them to be ignored.

Comment: I understood from the tutorial that when using @JsonView on the Controller method, the value of DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION would be set to false so that fields not annotated with a View are ignored and that is what I want. But this part is still not working, van I set that property somewhere without effecting all other uses of the Jackson converter?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I don't know how to set this view_inclusion property locally, but do you have to? DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION is advertised as 'false' by default, also: is there any other code that relies on @JsonViews? etc.

Comment: No there is not, but I would expect that when using @ JsonView, only the properties annotated with an @ JsonView(Views.MyView.class) should be serialized and the others ignored. 
Now fields annotated with another (not inherited) View as specified on the Controller method are ignored as expected but fields without @ JsonView annotation are shown and that is against my expectations. Not a showstopping issue but I would like it to work as I expect :)

Comment: then set DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION to false

Comment: According to the Spring documentation, this should already be false. Therefore it is stilla mystery to me why fields not annotated with @ JsonView are visible in the output...

Comment: From the fasterxml (JAckson) documentation:
public static final MapperFeature DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION
(...)

Default value is enabled, meaning that non-annotated properties are included in all views if there is no JsonView annotation.

So indeed it should be expected that when using the @ JsonView annotatino on a controller handler merthod, the non annotated properties in the DTO should not be visible. But in my example they are. IS there a way to check the current value of DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION?

Comment: have you seen the answer I linked to previously? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299334/jacksons-jsonview-annotation-does-not-work#38777244. The guy there is having a similar problem. Which version of jackson do you have? The sources have the ultimate say