# Spring MVC Ignore Json property for a given controller method

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Java class (`MyResponse`) that is returned by a multiple RestController methods and has a lot of fields.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "offering", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> postOffering(...) {}

@RequestMapping(value = "someOtherMethod", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> someOtherMethod(...) {}
```

I want to ignore (e.g. not serialize it) one of the properties for just one method.

I don't want to ignore null fields for the class, because it may have a side effect on other fields.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyResponse { ... }
```

The [JsonView](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) looks good, but as far as I understand I have to annotate all other fields in the class with a `@JsonView` except the one that I want to ignore which sounds clumsy. If there is a way to do something like "reverse JsonView" it will be great.

Any ideas on how to ignore a property for a controller method?

Comment: you could use @JsonIgnore but that would be for all methods. Maybe subclass it and ignore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Props to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299334/jacksons-jsonview-annotation-does-not-work#38777244) guy.

By default (and in Spring Boot) MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION is enabled in Jackson. That means that all fields are included by default.

But if you annotate any field with a view that is different than the one on the controller method this field will be ignored.

```
public class View {
    public interface Default{}
    public interface Ignore{}
}

@JsonView(View.Default.class) //this method will ignore fields that are not annotated with View.Default
@RequestMapping(value = "offering", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> postOffering(...) {}

//this method will serialize all fields
@RequestMapping(value = "someOtherMethod", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> someOtherMethod(...) {}

public class MyResponse { 
    @JsonView(View.Ignore.class)
    private String filed1;
    private String field2;
}
```