# Micronaut with Kotlin and Jackson's @JsonView annotation not working

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, jackson, micronaut

I'm experimenting with Micronaut and Kotlin.

I have a Hibernate JPA connection and it works pretty well, however, while creating a REST API for it, I wanted to exclude some properties from the listing serialization.

Therefore, here's what I did:

Domain class:

```
@Entity
@JsonView
class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    @JsonView(View1::class)
    var id : Long? = null

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true, length = 64)
    @JsonView(View1::class)
    lateinit var email : String

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 16)
    @JsonView(View2::class)
    lateinit var firstName : String

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 16)
    @JsonView(View2::class)
    lateinit var lastName : String

    @NotNull
    @JsonView(View2::class)
    lateinit var address : Address

}

@Embeddable
class Address {

    @Column(length = 64)
    lateinit var street : String

    @Column(length = 32)
    lateinit var city : String

    @Column(length = 16)
    lateinit var state : String
}
```

View1 and View2 are not interesting, as they are literally empty classes as per the documentation.

Now, in the controller, I do something like:

```
    @Get("/")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @JsonView(View1::class)
    fun list() : List<User> {
        return userRepository.findAll()
    }
```

Expecting some cooperation, however, this is what I got:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "john@doe.com",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "address": {
            "street": "23, Madison Street",
            "city": "Brooklyn",
            "state": "NY"
        }
    }
]
```

In the application.yml, json-view should be properly set as in:

```
jackson:
  json-view:
    enabled: true
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

After having the same problem I eventually stumbled onto this answer which was using the ObjectMapper directly: [Jackson's @JsonView annotation does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299334/jacksons-jsonview-annotation-does-not-work).

Problem was that the `jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion` property has a default value of true. Explicitly setting it to false in application.yml solved the issue for me.

```
jackson:
  serializationInclusion: ALWAYS
  json-view:
    enabled: true
  mapper:
    default-view-inclusion: false
```